# Can I use SpinalEnum as field in RegIf?

Tags: spinalhdl

I want to use `SpinalEnum` as `RegIf` field. Here is an example code, which doesn't seem to work:

```scala
object SourceEnum extends SpinalEnum {
  val src1, src2, src3 = newElement()
}

...

val busif = BusInterface(...)

// Control Register
val ctrl = busif.newReg("Control register")
val source = ctrl.field(SourceEnum.C, RW, doc = "Data source")
```

It shows a following error during compilation: `value C is not a member of object regiftest.SourceEnum`. I was using the `.C` type "extraction" before, and it worked, but clearly it doesn't work in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Currently, as a workaround I'm using `B(SourceEnum().getBitsWidth)` with `dest.assignFromBits(source)`, but it's not as elegant.

Comment: Am I right that there is a missing match here? https://github.com/SpinalHDL/SpinalHDL/blob/dev/lib/src/main/scala/spinal/lib/bus/regif/RegInst.scala#L135-L142

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't put SpinalEnum in.
the RegIf `REG.file()` only accept HardType like

```scala
val busif = BusInterface(...)

// Control Register
val ctrl = busif.newReg("Control register")
val source = ctrl.field(Bits(8 bit), RW, doc = "Data source")
val reg1 = ctrl.field(UInt(8 bit), RW, doc = "....")
val reg2 = ctrl.field(SInt(8 bit), RW, doc = "....")
val reg3 = ctrl.field(Bool(), RW, doc = "....")
```

or old way

```scala
val reg1 = ctrl.field(8 bit, RW, doc = "....")
val reg2 = ctrl.field(8 bit, RW, doc = "....")
val reg3 = ctrl.field(1 bit, RW, doc = "....")
```

For details, please refer to
https://spinalhdl.github.io/SpinalDoc-RTD/master/SpinalHDL/Libraries/regIf.html#